# C# 2D Arrays read from keyboard error

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

I have an error: "Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on line "v[i][j]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());" Kinda new to this object oriented languages, and am not sure what this means. Thanks!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int m, n, i, j;
    int[][] v=new int[10][];
    n=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    m=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       for(j=0;j<m;j++)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("v[{0}][{1}]= ", i, j);
          v[i][j]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<m;j++)
          Console.WriteLine("{0} ", v[i][j]);
       Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to change this:

```
int[][] v=new int[10][];
```

Because that code doesn't reserve memory for a 2D array.

It should be:

```
        int m, n, i, j;
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[,] v = new int[n,m];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("v[{0}][{1}]= ", i, j);
                v[i,j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ", v[i,j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

You can show [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) about multidimensional arrays from Microsoft.

Comment: Just tried like that and i got the same error. + getting 1 error : "Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'" on the line "int v[][]=new int[n][m];"

Comment: @clintrock I fixed it, sorry I used C style :S

Comment: @clintrock please mark this as solution, if it is the solution that you expected.

Answer (score 0):

A better way with C# is to declare it as a 2d array.

```
int [,] v = new int[10,10];
```

In this case, however, you find n and m later on, so it should read:

```
int [,] v = new int[n,m];
```